# How does flow trigger handle bulk DML operation?

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, lightning-flow-builder

I am looking into understanding the flow triggers and want to understand the below pointers:

1. Like we put common logic in generic/reusable methods in apex, can we do something like this in flows as well? For example, if I have a common roll-up logic say, count of contacts on the account record.
2. $Record could store one single record. How are we then able to perform bulk record operations in flows?
3. We cannot perform 'After Delete' and 'Undelete' operations. What could be done in case of above example (roll-up)?

Answer (score 1):

> Like we put common logic in generic/reusable methods in apex, can we do something like this in flows as well? For example, if I have a common roll-up logic say, count of contacts on the account record.

That's unnecessary. Flows automatically bulkify, as described in [Flow Bulkification in Transactions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5).

> $Record could store one single record. How are we then able to perform bulk record operations in flows?

Yes, as per above.

> We cannot perform 'After Delete' and 'Undelete' operations. What could be done in case of above example (roll-up)?

This is the reason why you need triggers for a proper rollup experience. As you've observed, deletes and undeletes don't trigger flows.